# AngularJS Filter Posts by Date not showing today's date

Tags: angularjs, date, filter, momentjs

I've got a list of events on a site I'm building and I would like the past events to be removed automatically. I've written a filter that is doing this, except it is removing today's events as well. I'm trying to use Angular Moment. Here is my code:

```
angular.module('zenCityApp')
  .filter('filterPastDates', function (moment) {
    return function (events) {
      var filterByDate = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {

        var currentDate = new Date();



        if(moment(currentDate).isBefore(events[i].date, 'hour')) {
          console.log("we're in!");
          filterByDate.push(events[i]);
          console.log(filterByDate);
        }


      }
      return filterByDate;
    };
  });
```

And here is the markup:

```
div ng-repeat="event in events | limitTo:100 | filter:tfilter | orderBy: 'date' | filterPastDates">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>{{event.date | amDateFormat:'MMMM Do'}}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>{{event.name}}</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you just need to change 'hour' to 'day', but you really should just declare currentDate once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be better is to create a cut-off `moment` for which you want to test.  Moments api gives you a pretty easy way to do it by using `.startOf('day')`.  That will give you a `moment` that represents today at 12:00am (the first second in the day).  But since you also want to include that value in your filter, you can then `subtract` 1 millisecond from the value.

```
var cutOffDate = moment().startOf('day').subtract(1,'millisecond');
```

And now you can easily use that in your filter.  Notice that I created that object outside of the loop (since it's not supposed to change), and I created it as a moment directly instead of creating a new moment object each time in the loop.

```
app.filter('filterPastDates', function () {
  return function (events) {
    if (events && events.length) {
      var filtered = [];
      var cutOffDate = moment().startOf('day').subtract(1,'millisecond');

      for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var evt = events[i];
        if (cutOffDate.isBefore(evt.date)) {
          filtered.push(evt);
        }
      }

      return filtered;
    } else {
      return events;
    }
  };

});
```

Here's a sample plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kSXu0Z3J7zoyBMBjoE84?p=preview